# How to process/deserialize array of string in Apex

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I am receiving the below output from lightning .js file by JSON.stringify

```
[
{"name":"test-0","PersonName":"John Smith","Product":"MASTERSTYLE-B-M","SKU":"BMV","level":2,"posInSet":1,"setSize":2,"isExpanded":true},
{"name":"test-1","PersonName":"John Smith","Product":"MASTERSTYLE-B-S","SKU":"LMV","level":2,"posInSet":2,"setSize":2,"isExpanded":true}
]
```

I want to deserialize the above output in Apex controller and I have to assign it to a wrapper class
I have tried many ways but I couldn't arrive a proper solution to this. If any one of you have any better solution or code or suggestion will be highly helpful.

**wrapper class**

```
public class OrderStatus{
        public String name {get;set;}
        public List<Products> productToUpdate {get;set;}
        public String PersonName{get;set;}

    }

    public class Products{
        public String SKU{get;set;}
        public String Product{get;set;}
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to deserialize this payload using the object structure you have, it will not capture all the data. It would look like:

```
List<OrderStatus> data = (List<OrderStatus>)JSON.deserialize(payload, List<OrderStatus>.class);
```

If you re-serialized it, what that would give you would be trimmed down to just:

```
[{
    "name":"test-0","PersonName":"John Smith"
}, {
    "name":"test-1","PersonName":"John Smith"
}]
```

If you want to update your `OrderStatus` class to capture all of the attributes, it would look like:

```
public class OrderStatus
{
    public String name { get; set; }
    public String PersonName { get; set; }
    public String Product { get; set; }
    public String SKU { get; set; }
    public Integerlevel { get; set; }
    public Integer posInSet { get; set; }
    public Integer setSize { get; set; }
    public Boolean isExpanded { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: My final output should be like this `{
 "name": "test-0",
 "Personname": "John", 
 
 "productToUpdate ": [{   
"Sku": "BMV",   
"Product": "MASTERSTYLE-B-M"   
  }, {
   "Sku": "LMV",   
   "Product": "MASTERSTYLE-B-M"   
  }
 ]
 
}`

Comment: The structure of the data you are passed does not match that.